# Oracle get column data size

Tags: oracle, types

I'm new to Oracle db, and i wonder if i can find out the datatype and datasize...
I mean : let's say i have the column "location" of type varchar2(20) in table "products".
Could i write a query that would return me in the result "varchar2" and "20" ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 33):

Check out [user_tab_columns](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_2094.htm#I1020277).

```
select data_type, data_length 
  from user_tab_columns
 where table_name = 'PRODUCTS'
   and column_name = 'LOCATION';
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you need to find out the type and size of a column for the purpose of understanding the data, or are you writing a program that needs to know it at runtime?

If you only need to know it for your knowledge, typing `desc tablename` in SQLPlus will tell you about the columns in the table.

If you need to find out the type and size programmatically, what language are you using ... PL/SQL?  Java?

Note that selecting from USER_TAB_COLUMNS will only list the columns in tables in your own schema.  For other tables you'll need to look at ALL_TAB_COLUMNS (or DBA_TAB_COLUMNS, if the DBA has allowed you to access it).  Note that your employer or client may disallow stored procedures or packages from being compiled against either.

Answer (score 4):

I do the following from sqlplus for oracle:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE,DATA_LENGTH 
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOUR_TABLE_NAME'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'YOUR';`
```

Hope it works for you too!

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT CHAR_LENGTH FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = <TABLENAME> AND COLUMN_NAME = <COLUMNNAME>;
```

Comment: I forgot to add DATA_TYPE in the Select clause.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this question was useful to me. But, there is one important difference needs to be considered while taking data_length when the column type is `NVARCAHR2`. The data_length returned for `NVARCHA2` column is doubled.

This is due to the character encoding being used. 
[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF50950) says:

> The number of bytes can be up to two times size for AL16UTF16
>   encoding and three times size for UTF8 encoding.

So, ideal query would be the following:

```
select table_name, column_name, 
data_type, NVL(char_col_decl_length, data_length) 
from user_tab_columns where table_name='T51_NOCOMP';
```